# CSS how to change color of a specific primary-panel in a if-block

Tags: css

I have many panels and want to change the color of a primary-panel after the counter is 10;

```
this.dateUpdate = function (element) {
      if (hasfocus == element) {
         dateCounter += 1;
          if (dateCounter == 10) {
              element.addClass('changecolor');
              dateCounter = 0;
           }
      } 
  };
```

This is not working:

```
.changecolor > .panel-primary {
   background-color: #e1e1e1 !important;
}
```

to remember, I just want to change the specific one, and not all.

Thx in advance.

Comment: try replacing changecolor with panel-primary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If the `panel-primary` div is inside `changecolor` div**

```
.changecolor .panel-primary {
   background-color: #e1e1e1 !important;
}
```

**If the `panel-primary` div is the same div in which `changecolor` class is getting applied**

```
.changecolor.panel-primary {
   background-color: #e1e1e1 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of `element.addClass` try `element.setAttribute("class", "changecolor");`

Comment: I got the error: element.setAttribute is not a function